# Eccentricity of a conic in planet motion

Tags: calculus

A planet moves around Sun as focal point at origin in a conic orbit with semi latus-rectum $p$, angle between radius vector and tangential velocity $\psi$  and arc-rate $ \psi^{ \prime}.$

Find its eccentricity $e$ in terms of the above three invariants of motion.

EDIT 1:

Happy to conclude the definition as follows after verification.

As radius vector $r$, polar angle $\theta$ are Euclidean motions ( of translation / rotation in the plane) eccentricity $e$  need not be a function of these. So deleted them from original question.

Starting from previously derived results:

$$ \dfrac { d\psi}{dr} = \tan \psi \left( \dfrac{\sin^2 \psi}{p} - \dfrac{1}{r} \right) \tag{1} $$

which integrate to the following (when $ (a,b) $ are ellipse semi-axes),

$$ (r -r_1)(r-r_2) = 0, \quad r_{1,2}= a \pm \sqrt{ \left( a^2 - (b / \sin\, \psi \right)^2} \tag{2}  $$

The apogee/perigee distances are

$$ ( a+c, a-c) $$

at $\psi = (k-\frac12) \pi \tag{3}  $

Eccentricity $e$ is derived as:

$$  \boxed{ e= \sqrt{ {\cos^2 \psi} + \left( \frac{p \psi{\prime}}{\sin^2 \psi}   \right )^2 } } \tag{4} $$

EDIT 2:

The above are based on my definition of conics curvature in the plane:

$$ k_g = \psi^{\prime}+ \frac{\sin \psi}{r} = \frac{\sin^3\psi}{p} \tag{5}$$

which gives *Differential  Equation  of all conics in the plane* in terms of isometric inclination of radius vector and arc of conic $\psi$ including arc rates with arbitrary Euclidean motions of rigid conics:

$$ \tan \psi \cdot \psi ^{\prime \prime} = 2 \psi ^{\prime ^2} + \left({\dfrac{\sin^3 \psi }{p}}\right) ^2  \tag{6} $$

which is also the verified result by eliminating eccentricity $e$ as an arbitrary constant.

Comment: What is a ‘rectum’?

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore What's wrong with that?

Comment: Time  ago in a related formulation I established the intrinsic differential equation of any conic as, but not connectable to the eccentricity question here, so I posted this.
$ \dfrac { d\psi}{dr} = \tan \psi \left( \dfrac{\sin^2 \psi}{p} - \dfrac{1}{r} \right) $